# Flutter Equatable Real Life Usage?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, hashcode, equatable

I have learned that what is the Equatable and how can I use it. But I just wonder that why should I use it?

I have found some reasons. One of them, when we wants to compare 2 or more same object from any class, it will use. they aren't same even if they properties same because of hash code. But equatable compares each other without hash code.

But I really wonder that where I will use in real life scenario?

Many Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default 2 reference objects compare by references this means if you will create two equal objects and try to compare they will be different because references are different and you have manually check each field with each field of another object. For detailed information on `equals` and `hasCode` concept, you can read [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-equals-hashcode).

As a result, if the object doesn't have specific `equals` and `hashCode` then you can't use such objects in the `Set`, `Map`, `HashTables` and other data structures.

Another real example of this is unit tests. It will be very exhausting for you to write tests where you have to compare actual result with expected ones because on each test you have to compare each field instead of just using the `equivalency` operator(==).

Remember, this is not a `dart` feature this is a **standard** approach in **computer science** and **data structures**.

Comment: that is my searching answer. I mean, I'm gonna use various circumstances like api or test. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [overview section](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable#overview) describes well

> By default, == returns true if two objects are the same instance.

```dart
class Bar {
  final int a = 2;
}

print(Bar() == Bar()); //false
```

While you like to judge instance/objects by its fields, we can use Equatable. A common use case when we like to update state(Check Bloc state-management)

```dart
class Foo extends Equatable {
  final int a = 2;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [a];
}

  print(Foo() == Foo()); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume we have this `user` class model:

```
class User extends Equatable {
  final String fullName;
  final int phone;
  const User({
    required this.fullName,
    required this.phone,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [fullName, phone];
}
```

and we have these variable:

```
var myUser = User(fullName: 'Amir', phone: 123456);
List<User> users = [
    User(fullName: 'Amir', phone: 123456),
    User(fullName: 'Amir 2', phone: 5353453),
    User(fullName: 'Amir 3', phone: 78978978),
];
```

and now we want to search in our `users` and if `myUser` is in users list remove it:

```
users.remove(myUser);
```

if we don't use `Equatable` on `User` we could find it. but now we can.